# Inverse of nonnegative Toeplitz matrice

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus

Consider a right-hand circulant matrice of size $n$ (called also Toeplitz matrice)
\begin{equation}
T=
\left( \begin{array}{ccccc}
a_1 & a_2 & a_3 & \ldots & a_n \\
a_n & a_1 & a_2 & \ldots & a_{n-1}\\
\vdots\\
a_2 & a_3 & a_4 & \ldots & a_1
\end{array} \right)
\end{equation}

$\{a_i\}$ are nonnegative and not all equal.

Is $T$ alwayls invertible?

I proved that:

$\bullet$ for n=2 the $Det(T) = (a_1+a_2)(a_1-a_2) \neq 0$ $

$\bullet$ for n=3 the $Det(T) = \frac{1}{2}(a_1+a_2+a_3)\left( (a_1-a_2)^2 + (a_1-a_3)^2(a_2-a_3)^2 \right) \neq 0$

What about $n>3$?

Comment: If all elements are different to each other and nonnegatives, is all columns ( rows) linear independent?

Comment: How do you prove that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a long hint: does writing $T$ as a linear combination of the powers of $P $ where $p_{i i-1} = 1$ and zero every where else. $P$ has eigenvalues the $n$th roots of unity. so $T$ thaw $a_1+a_2\omega+a_3\omega^2+\cdots$ and the determinant of $T$ is the product of 
$(a_1+a_2\omega+a_3\omega^2+\cdots)(a_1+a_2\omega+a_3\omega^2+\cdots))\cdots$

showing that the determinant is nonzero reduces to showing that all the factors are nonzero. that is if $\omega$ in an $n$th root of unity and $a_1, a_2, \cdots$ are non negative and not all equal, then $$(a_1+a_2\omega+a_3\omega^2+\cdots )\neq 0$$

it is more likely to be true if $n$ is a prime number. i am not sure if it is true for nonprime numbers. e.g., take $n = 4, \omega = i, a_1 = a2 = -a_3 = -a_4 = 1 $

Comment: whoever down voted, can you your reason for down voting?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your example is correct but in my case the $a_i$s are nonnegative...So now one need to proove that if $\sum_{i=1}^{n}{a_i w^{i-1}}=0$ then $a_i=0$

Comment: @John,sorry, for a moment i forgot that all $a_i$'s are nonnegative. assertion may still be true.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $n$ is even

Take $a_1=a_3=...=a_{n-1}$ and $a_2=a_4=...=a_n$.

Then $T$ is not invertible since the rows are not independant.

For $n$ odd, I tend to think $T$ is invertible.